# Excel VSTO Workbook in Onedrive/Sharepoint

Tags: excel, vsto, onedrive

Do you know how to save an Excel VSTO Workbook project on a OneDrive or a sharepoint?
I would like other people to be able access to the Workbook and modify it.
For the moment I'm stuck as I keep getting an error message saying that the path I chose (OneDrive) is not a trusted location. It keeps popping up even though I declared the path as a trusted location in the Trust Center Options of Excel.

Thanks a lot for your help!